# Bike feels like it's slipping/shifting gear when pedalling while standing up on max gear

Tags: mountain-bike

not familiar with bike terminology, so sorry if this doesn't come across well. My bike will make a loud clicking noise and the pedals will give some resistance when I pedal whilst standing up. If I sit down it is perfectly fine. Shifting down to lower gears allow me to stand up and pedal with no issues whatsoever. It's hard to see what exactly is going on when the only time I can get the issue to occur is when I'm standing up on the bike.

Hope someone can help me out!

Comment: There are a number of options here. I would look at your bottom bracket bearings, and the teeth on the bike's gears.

Comment: Gidday and welcome to SE Bicycles.  Clear photos of your chain area might help diagnose whats up.  How old is the bike?  Did this start suddenly or has it got worse gradually?  Have a browse through the tour at http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/tour to find out how the stack works.

Comment: A cassette may slip under high torque when the free hub splines are worn, if so this could explain the 'slipping'. But then you also describe the problem as extra resistance, could point to damaged bearings in any of several places, but sounds like the opposite to 'slipping'! So can you be clearer about the problem?

Comment: What sort of drivetrain are we talking here, how many speeds, are you cross chaining perhaps? Going from the far side of the crankset to the opposite side of the cassette? Cause that's a no no and will result in something similar, if that is not the case the other answers/comments are all viable

Answer (score 4):

Chain is probably jumping on cassette.

This could be just a stiff chain.  Clean and lube the chain.

If not a stiff chain then more likely a worn chain and or cassette/freewheel. When they are worn they don't match up well and can jump.

If by lower you mean mean the bigger diameter gears they are less likely to jump as they have more teeth touching.

You can get a relative cheap [tool](http://www.parktool.com/product/chain-checker-cc-2?category=Chain) to check for chain stretch.  If the chain is stretched then replace it.  Cassette/freewheel is a little harder to measure wear - I bring up a picture of a new one and compare.  Or just buy a new one and compare.  Or just post a picture of it in you question.  If you replace the cassette/freewheel then always replace the chain.  You can get like 2-3 chains per cassette.

Comment: Before replacing the chain, you MUST check your cassette wear. Otherwise you can wear your new chain really quick.